# Use keras model restored from GridFS

Tags: python, mongodb, machine-learning, keras, gridfs

I`d like to use a model that is stored in GridFS.
I'm trying this:

```
gout = fs.get(ObjectId(objectID))
fout=gout.read()
```

Where `fout` has my model in bytes, but I don't know how to use it like a model, cause if I try to use directly `(y_pred = fout.predict(X))` , I obtain this error: `'bytes' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Comment: How was the model saved? I mean in which format, HDF5?

Comment: I'm really not sure, i use this code to upload It to GridFS:                                        
        conn =MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(conn.grid_model)
        modelo = model.to_json()
        fs.put(modelo, filename="model")

Comment: to_json() will only save a JSON representation of the architecture, it does not contain the weights, so this model is kind of useless without the weights.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try then without passing it to json, thank you very much!

Comment: That goes back to my original question, you need to save it as HDF5, which will contain both weights and model architecture.